# Reduced quadratic forms, reduced ideals, bounds of coefficients

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have a question about the connection between ideals an forms.
Let $f =(a,b,c)$ be integral primitive positive definite binary quadratic forms and $\Delta$ be the discriminant.

It is clear, that if $(a,b,c)$ is reduced, then $a \leq \sqrt{\vert \Delta \vert /3}$.
I also know that the group of classes of quadratic forms of discriminant $\Delta$, is isomorphic to the class group of the quadratic number field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\Delta})$.

So my question is, if $ I=[a,\frac{b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}]$ is a reduced ideal, then it  should also apply that $a\leq \sqrt{\vert \Delta\vert /3}$.
But e.g. in "binary quadratic forms an algorithm approach" from Buchmann and Vollmer (and other books) they say on page 178 that $a< \sqrt{\vert \Delta\vert /3}$.

Comment: This is a misprint. If $\Delta = -3$, the bound is sharp since $a$ is nonzero for any basis of the ideal.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks a lot!